# Database Row Deletion Integration With Discord.py Not Deleting

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

So I have a pretty solid program going so far, I'm at the last step of this process. This part of the program is where when the user types `!view` then the Discord bot displays all rentals in the database in separate embeds. Each embed then has a trashcan emoji underneath it that when the user clicks it, it deletes the Discord message. The only missing piece is that when they click the trashcan emoji I want it to delete the Discord message (which it does) as well as delete the row from the database. I have in column 1 the id, so I have an idea of how to do it, but it just doesn't work in the last function. Here is what I have:

```
    if message.content.startswith('!view'):
        rows = cursor.execute("SELECT id, name, renter, duration, price, start, end FROM rental").fetchall()
        for x in rows:
            embed = discord.Embed(title='Rental #{}'.format(x[0]), color=0x0000FF)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://www.pngkit.com/png/detail/231-2316751_database-database-icon-png.png')
            embed.add_field(name='Bot Name:', value=x[1], inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Renter Name:', value=x[2], inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Rental Duration:', value='{} day(s)'.format(x[3]), inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Rental Price:', value='${}'.format(x[4]), inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Start Date:', value=x[5], inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='End Date:', value=x[6], inline=False)
            embed.set_footer(icon_url='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1325672283881484289/oaGtVIOD_400x400.png', text='Created by @Expected')
            msg = await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
            await msg.add_reaction('\U0001F5D1')

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.user_id == client.user.id:
        return

    if str(payload.emoji) == '\U0001F5D1':
        channel = await client.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
        await message.delete()
        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM rental WHERE id={}".format(x[0]))
        connection.commit()
```

The second to last line of the `on_raw_reaction_add` function is where the problem occurs. Before I got to this semi-working code I had just the database deletion working when it was just outside of the for loop `cursor.execute("DELETE FROM rental WHERE id={}".format(x[0]))` , since x is in the for loop it works, but when I bring x out of the loop and into another function it obviously is read as an undefined variable. I then tried making `rows` a global variable and using `rows[0][0]` to get the id to delete, but that didn't work. Nothing was deleted from the database. It was also the wrong row, as `x[0]` gets the most recently added row and id from that row. So I then tried to `ORDER BY id ASC` in the rows cursor execute, but to no avail I got the error that sqlite3.cursor is not subscriptable. I'm kind of out of ideas, maybe one of my ideas would work but I'm just executing it in the wrong way. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to bring the query results from one function scope to another you could get the ID from your message embed:

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.user_id == client.user.id:
        return

    if str(payload.emoji) == '\U0001F5D1':
        channel = await client.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
        try:        
            embed = message.embeds[0]
            # Extract number from title after #
            rental_id = embed.title.rsplit('#', 1)[1]
        except: # Very broad catch for shortness
            # Message has no embed or title is not in correct format
            return
        await message.delete()
        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM rental WHERE id={}".format(rental_id))
        connection.commit()
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! I'm always overthinking these solutions, using the id in the embed (which is the same id I was try to get anyways) is a MUCH simpler way. Thanks again :)